# How to set default directory in Bitvise SSH Client, using its CMD?

Tags: ssh, command-line

In `Bitvise SSH Client`, there is a tab called 'terminal' and in there I can see 'execute remote command', so I tried to put : `ls` for example to test, but it's not working.

And what I want to do is, set a default directory so I will not do `Cd dir1\dir2`.

each time I log in, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that i can edit the `.bashrc` file at the root directory and all i have to do is to add at the end the `Cd dir1\dir2` and save.